# How do you convert an array of bitboards into a list?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chess

Please correct me if I'm wrong. The search algorithm, i.e. modified alpha beta, explores a list of legal moves. Firstly, one needs to initialize 
an array of bitboards like this:

unsigned long long knight_attacks[64]= {0x020800, 0x050800 and so on...}

Each element will have 1's on all possible attack squares from that square,e.g.., knight_attacks[f4] will have 1's on d5, e6, g6, h5, d3, e2, g2, and h3 corresponding to the possible attack squares from f4.

Once this has been initialized one needs to somehow convert into a list...

How do you covert an array of bitboards into a list?
thanks for the help brothers and sisters.

Comment: There's no rule saying you don't need to use bitboards if you're uncomfortable using them.

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution consists in looping over bits of the bitboards:

```
while ( x ) {
   U64 ls1b = x & -x; // isolate LS1B
   ...
   x &= x-1; // reset LS1B
}
```

More advanced algorithms can be found in the chess programming wiki:
https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Bitboard+Serialization

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm wrong; I'm just a beginner.

knight moves are broken up into 2 types: captures, and non captures.

for both noncapture and capture moves you will need to use bitwise OR,but, obviously use different bitboards.

knightCaptures = knightAttack bitboard | emptySquare;

likewise;

knightMoves = knightAttack bitboard | enemyBitboard;

to convert each of these bitboards into a list of moves you need to do the following: scan the bit board for each bit. how do you do this? by finding the least significant bit and removing it. Then you find the next lowest sig bit and remove it...so on.

the following are some articles on move generation and bitscan:
https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BitScan

http://peterellisjones.com/post/39938456375/chess-engine-part-i-choosing-internal-data

http://peterellisjones.com/post/41238723473/chess-engine-part-ii-move-encoding-and-move

https://www.cis.uab.edu/hyatt/boardrep.html

https://www.cis.uab.edu/hyatt/bitmaps.html

this is on all the theory behind chess engines:

http://www.frayn.net/beowulf/theory.html